grouping for stdout
When commands are grouped with parentheses, the stdin for the next command is collected from all the grouped commands, eg
user@system:~$ (echo 1; echo 2; echo -e '3\n4') | tac
4
3
2
1

vs
user@system:~$ echo 1; echo 2; echo -e '3\n4' | tac
1
2
4
3

Is there a way to do the inverse of this, where the stdout of one command goes to all the grouped commands, eg
user@system:~$ echo -e '1\n2\n3\n4\n5' | (tail -n2; head -n2)
4
5
1
2

One specific useful example for this could be a table with a header:
user@system:~$ cat datatable.md | (head -n2; sed '1,2d' | sort)

Ideally, you’d use a utility that understands the format of your data. If it’s CVS or a similar format, there are tools that knows that the first record (possibly several lines) constitutes a header.

Somewhat related: tee for commands

In:

cat datatable.md | (head -n2; sed '1,2d' | sort)


The output of cat does go to both head and sed. head and sed share the same stdin which is the reading end of the pipe cat is writing to.
But most head implementations read their input in large chunks, so, it will likely read more than 2 lines and even the whole input, even if it's only outputting the first 2 lines of it.
And because, the input is a pipe instead of a regular file, it can't seek back to the end of those 2 lines in the input as POSIX requires for seekable files.
Here concatenating a single file makes little sense, you can do:
{ head -n2 && sort; } < database.md

Where the input is a regular file this time, so is seekable.
I've also replaced the (...) which is to run a subshell, with { ...;} which is to group commands, and sed 1,2d|sort with just sort as I assume you want to sort the rest of the input (from lines 3) rather than skipping 2 extra lines (for which tail -n+3 would be more obvious).
If you do to use a pipe, you can replace head with something that reads the first two lines one byte at a time or can be convinced to.
With the GNU implementation of sed, you can do:
$  seq 10 | { sed -u 2q && sort -rn; }
1
2
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3

Or you could do:
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR <= 2 {print; next}; {print | "sort -rn"}'
1
2
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3


You got answers to the specific question you asked but if you want to sort parts of a file as in the example you provided at the end of your question the consider employing a Decorate-Sort-Undecorate approach, e.g. given this input:
$ printf 'first hdr\nsecond hdr\nz\nb\na\nx\n'
first hdr
second hdr
z
b
a
x

and using any version of these Unix tools to sort the lines after a 2-line header:
$ printf 'first hdr\nsecond hdr\nz\nb\na\nx\n' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>2), NR, $0}' |
    sort -k1,1n -k3 -k2,2n |
    cut -f 3-
first hdr
second hdr
a
b
x
z

To see what that's doing, remove the pipe to sort and cut, then add sort back:
Decorate (add information about line numbers to sort on):
$ printf 'first hdr\nsecond hdr\nz\nb\na\nx\n' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>2), NR, $0}'
0       1       first hdr
0       2       second hdr
1       3       z
1       4       b
1       5       a
1       6       x

Sort (sort first by the "line nr less than 3" bit then sort the input data, then sort by original line number to preserve input order for duplicates):
$ printf 'first hdr\nsecond hdr\nz\nb\na\nx\n' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>2), NR, $0}' |
    sort -k1,1n -k3 -k2,2n
0       1       first hdr
0       2       second hdr
1       5       a
1       4       b
1       6       x
1       3       z

Undecorate (remove the line number info added in step 1):
$ printf 'first hdr\nsecond hdr\nz\nb\na\nx\n' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>2), NR, $0}' |
    sort -k1,1n -k3 -k2,2n |
    cut -f 3-
first hdr
second hdr
a
b
x
z


The best I can think of is something like this:
mkfifo /tmp/fifo_{1,2}

head -n2 < /tmp/fifo_1 &
(sed '1,2d' < /tmp/fifo_2 | sort)&

echo -e '1\n2\n3\n4\n5' | tee /tmp/fifo_1 /tmp/fifo_2 | md5sum


One specific useful example for this could be a table with a header:
cat datatable.md | (head -n2; sed '1,2d' | sort)

That problem is trivially solved by a different pattern: concatenating pipes; you don't need "split streams" for this at all.

what do you mean by concatenating pipes, if that's something different than the mkfifo in your answer? (the cat datatable.md is just a stand-in for other arbitrary pipes)

hmm. In general, I'd be wary of running parallel tasks like this, as there's usually nothing to guarentee they run in the correct order for the output to come up right. I suppose it helps here that sort has to read all of its input before printing anything, so head is likely to be faster. This may also be sensitive to the pipe buffer size, in that tee may need to block on some of the writes, and that can again affect the timing. And worse, when head stops reading and exits, tee will get a SIGPIPE and it may die, leaving the other task missing part of the data.

@ilkkachu you're of course right, you'd want to redirect the outputs themselves, and potentially output them in an ordered fashion;

e.g. on my Mac, this bash -c 'head -n2 < /tmp/fifo_1 & (sed '1,2d' < /tmp/fifo_2 | sort -rn)  & seq 9999 | tee  /tmp/fifo_1 /tmp/fifo_2 > /dev/null; wait' |head -3 prints only about 3500 lines (including for some reason, a 3 twice at the end(?))
